# NODE_ENV is not comparing correctly in an Express app

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run an express app using Next.js. I have mostly got it under control, but for some reason the package.json does assign NODE_ENV to the correct value, but the comparing the two does not seem to work.

Scripts in json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon start server.js",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "set NODE_ENV=production && node server.js"
},
```

The app:

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
```

No matter what I do, it seems to assign the value correctly, but the comparison always returns true. If I try to do an if-else statement using == or === it all passes as it doesn't match. I've console them both in tandem, adding a number to the end to see the difference, and everything aside the added number was correct.

Comment: this works if you use Mac or Linux, on Windows you should use something like [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) or [dot-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-env)

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json use :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon start server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
},
```

Observe I have removed the `set` and the `&&` in your start script.
After this is done ensure you are executing the script by executing

```
npm start
```

If you still face problems, console.log the `process.env.NODE_ENV` to cross-check what you are getting.

Comment: "'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Thats the first thing I tried, ended up with that message, which is why I did set, &&.

Comment: was there a space after NODE_ENV. There should not be

Comment: Nope, no spaces.